# Spark RDD.saveAsTextFile asynchronously

Tags: apache-spark

I have a big RDD which takes a lot of time to `collect`.
I thought to have every partition write its contents to a text file by using `mapPartitionsWithIndex`. But this is not an async method.

Does any body have an idea how to write out RDD contents asynchronously?

Comment: Why do you Collect? Just write to text. It isn't asynchronous but it is distributed

Comment: I don't quite understand the question either. You mention `saveAsTextFile` in the title, then talk about `collect` and `mapPartitionsWithIndex` in the question. Anyway I tried to provide an answer.

Comment: the problem with saveastextfile is that you can't read result files until entire task has finished, only then i can start copying the files to the driver and start loading, that is a waste of good time !!, that's why i thought about first splitting using mapPartitionWithIndex and than asyncSaveAsTextFile.

Comment: Also, do we have a better way to get an rdd of each partition without using mapPartitionsWithIndex, which take some time to run

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Spark RDD actions are synchronous. `AsyncRDDActions` provides async versions of some of them, but not `saveAsTextFile`. It is trivial to wrap it in a `Future` yourself though:

```
def saveAsync(rdd: RDD[String], path: String) = concurrent.Future {
  rdd.saveAsTextFile(path)
}
```

Comment: All is a little bit to strong. There is `AsyncRDDActions` after all :)